# PHP to JSON encode with associative array

Tags: php, json, associative-array

```
require "constant.php";
require "database.php";
$sql = "select e.*, b.booth_address, ba.bank_full_name from $app_booth_enrolment e
left join $app_booth_info b on e.booth_id=b.booth_id
left join $app_bank_info ba on e.bank_id=ba.bank_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        array_push($data,$row);
    }
    echo $data = json_encode($data);  
    var_dump(json_encode($data));
}else{
    $data['status'] = "No terminal found";
    echo $data = json_encode($data);
}
```

The `echo json_encode($data);` print nothing but `print_r($data)` print an array. How to convert the data array to json format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [enrolment_id] => 101-1-0001
            [terminal_type_id] => ATM
            [booth_name] => CITY-Bashundhara
            [enrolment_date] => 2015-01-01
            [live_date] => 2015-02-02
            [bank_id] => 101
            [booth_id] => 101-0001
            [terminal_serial] => 5300153835
            [terminal_host] => TCBL-TWO
            [terminal_app] => 
            [note] => 
            [status] => 1
            [insert_by] => 1
            [insert_date] => 
            [booth_address] => Head Office, Jiban Bima Tower, 10, Dilkusha Commercial Area, Dhaka-1000 
            [bank_full_name] => The City Bank Limited
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [enrolment_id] => 101-1-0002
            [terminal_type_id] => ATM
            [booth_name] => CITY-VIP_Road
            [enrolment_date] => 2015-01-01
            [live_date] => 2015-02-02
            [bank_id] => 101
            [booth_id] => 101-0002
            [terminal_serial] => 5300153831
            [terminal_host] => TCBL-TWO
            [terminal_app] => 
            [note] => 
            [status] => 1
            [insert_by] => 1
            [insert_date] => 
            [booth_address] => Head Office, Jiban Bima Tower, 10, Dilkusha Commercial Area, Dhaka-1000 
            [bank_full_name] => The City Bank Limited
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [enrolment_id] => 101-2-0003
            [terminal_type_id] => CDM
            [booth_name] => CITY-DSE
            [enrolment_date] => 2015-01-01
            [live_date] => 2015-02-02
            [bank_id] => 101
            [booth_id] => 101-0003
            [terminal_serial] => 5300153832
            [terminal_host] => TCBL-TWO
            [terminal_app] => 
            [note] => 
            [status] => 1
            [insert_by] => 1
            [insert_date] => 
            [booth_address] => Head Office, Jiban Bima Tower, 10, Dilkusha Commercial Area, Dhaka-1000 
            [bank_full_name] => The City Bank Limited
        ) 
)
```

Comment: try using yii2 encode() function: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basejson.html#encode%28%29-detail

Comment: can you show us what is there in  `print_r($data) `?

Comment: What exactly does `var_dump(json_encode($data));` return

Comment: `json_encode()` should do the trick, that is it does ... show us your Array

Comment: The array is given,please help.

Comment: var_dump(json_encode($data));  return bool(false)

Comment: If that is the case you should then call [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see what's gone wrong

Comment: echo json_last_error_msg() return Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the solution.

Havelock suggested to print `json_last_error_msg()` and I found malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.

I am using `MySQLi` so I have to put this line in after database connection for character formatting: `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");`.

Thanks Havelock.